# Google Tag Manager Event Tracking- Optional Parameters

Tags: events, tracking, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Does anyone know of a custom event tracking paramater i can use in Google Tag Manager(Universal Analytics) that can pass along additional information
*other* than the standard **category, label, and action** attributes? I can't
use 'value' attribute as that only appears to be a numerical value. I want to
pass along additional text.

I would like to be able to basically pass along a second label attribute.4

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You can send [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) with any interaction hit (pageviews, events etc.). Custom Dimensions are user defined fields that hold a string value. However they do not show up in the standard reports, you would have to set a custom reports that includes your event category, label, action and the custom dimension.

In the Universal Analytis tag  template you can set up custom dimensions in the advanced settings ("Add custom dimension", enter the numeric index and enter the value, or macro that holds the value).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer yourself, or have access to one, you can also write custom JS to push any variable and value to the dataLayer, in addition to the C, A, and L. For example:

```
dataLayer.push({event: 'myEvent', category: 'myCategory', action: 'myAction', customVar1: 'customValue'});
```

Hope that helps!